# no internet on cloned virtual machine (Vmware workstation)

Tags: centos, vmware-workstation

so i setup a centOS vm in VMware workstation, installed qradar..everything ran fine. I call this vm as QR1.

I was able to use qradar console on QR1 from my host machine, the internet works perfectly fine in QR1.
I make a full clone of QR1 called it QR2.

I boot it up and only running QR2 vm (QR1 is closed) but there is no internet on this vm. Even though all the network setting are same as QR1 and QR1 works just fine(i double checked).
QR2 has same adapter, same ip, same gateway and dns as of QR1 but it doesnt work...

previously i was thinking that i cannot have them both running at same time but QR2 just doesnt connect.
I am also not able to ping QR2 from my host and other way around.

What could be causing this ?

Comment: Is the network checkbox in the VMware devices menu enable? If it is, when you reset that what will be happen?

Comment: if you mean networking is ON? then yes it is on.

Comment: i dont know how you can reset the network in vm..

Comment: did you try this solution? **https://kb.vmware.com/articleview?docid=2002767&lang=en_US**

Comment: As you know, two VMs with same mac address can't be running at the same time, but in this case (Just one VM is running) is strange?!

Comment: ya the link you shared made it work.
the problem was that upon cloning the internal (inside OS) the ip,mac etc remained the same but the VM assigns different mac address which results in miss-match of mac adresses hence no network.
I did not pay attention to the mac address in the beginning.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this vmware link](https://kb.vmware.com/articleview?docid=2002767&lang=en_US) reference, try these steps:

To change the MAC address of the Linux operating system:

> Connect to vCenter Server using the vSphere Client Right-click the
>   virtual machine and click Edit Settings. Click Network adapter and
>   note the MAC Address.
>
> For example, you see a MAC Address similar to:
>
> xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>
> **1.Power on the Linux virtual machine.**
>
> **2.Open a console and log in as root.**
>
> **3.Change directory to etc/sysconfig/network-scripts.**
>
> **4.Edit ifcfg-eth0 using a plain text editor and update the MAC address to reflect the MAC address in Step 3.**